# Bootstrap DatePicker shows wrong date on calender

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap Date picker in MVC c# application. I've bind date picker with current date. Format of date picker is dd/mm/yyyy.

**Jquery**
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
          format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
          autoclose: true
    });

**Razor**

```
@Html.TextBox("AppointmentDate", @Model.NewAppointmet.Appointment_Date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Appointment Date", id = "AppointmentDate" })
```

When Page load, datepicker shows correct date
[image]

But When I open datepicker it shows wrong date
[image]

Comment: Hey buddy , did you got any thing regarding this issue ? I am also getting the same issue. Please provide the solution if you have. ;)

Comment: My answer seems to be late but as the saying goes better late than never.
I had a similar issue with my date picker, to fix the issue i switched to a different date picker [new datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). This fixed my issue. it seems the previous datepicker was not using the specified format to parse the date on the users laptop. hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

MM: Abbreviated and full month names(eg. January)

try using this code

```
@Html.TextBox("AppointmentDate", @Model.NewAppointmet.Appointment_Date.Value.ToString('dd/mm/yyyy'), new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Appointment Date", id = "AppointmentDate" })
```

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers seriously?

Comment: @RohanShewale really, because `mm` mean minutes.

Comment: I referred here:https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format

Answer (score -2):

Try this in jquery. Try using capital M instead of m

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ format: "dd/MM/yyyy", autoclose: true });
```

Comment: I want to display date in specific dd/mm/yyyy format, then why should I set format MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers try using MM instead of mm. mm is used for minutes and MM is for Month. See the edited answer.